# Cannot delete a file on WSL Ubuntu 20.02.2

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is probably cause by closing the WSL when delete process not complete. And now I want to delete this file.

---

`ls -lba` output this

```
root@A12581:/HelloWorld/android-kernel/.repo/projects/prebuilts/boot-artifacts.git# ls -lba
ls: cannot access '.repo_config.json': No such file or directory
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 28 09:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 15:56 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? .repo_config.json
```

---

but I'm unable to delete this file / delete the folder contain this file / rename the folder contain this file

---

my environment :

WSL1

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: This is usually a sign of file system corruption. Unfortunately, WSL1 does not have a mechanism to repair its file indices. You may want to do yourself a favour and rebuild the container ... perhaps with WSL2.

Comment: The error message is saying that the file does not exist. Check to make sure that the path exists and that it is inside your wsl file system. You most likely either had a typo in the file pathname, or else the file is outside of the WSL filesystem (e.g. it is on your Windows drive). Remember, wsl acts on resources on the wsl filesystem, which is usually created alongside your C drive, and often on  a completely different drive..

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?  A similar issue popped up today on the Unix & Linux Stack.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds sorry to say, but it seems there's no other way except to take a backup and re-install entire system

Answer (score 0):

@matigo is probably correct with the comment regarding filesystem corruption.  I also agree that the WSL2 use of ext4 is almost certainly more robust if it fits your needs.

If you haven't already, do a `wsl --shutdown` (from PowerShell) to make sure any handles/locks are released.  Then restart and try again.  It has a relatively small chance of working, but it's worth a shot since it's so quick.

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend the following for attempting to repair the WSL1 instance.

Basically round-trip the WSL1 instance through a `wsl --export`/`wsl --import`.  The `tar` round-trip that this process performs *should* (hopefully) remove the corrupted file when archiving or unarchiving, one or the other.

From PowerShell:

```
# Confirm the distribution name
wsl -l -v
# Distribution name may be "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu-20.04" - Adjust the following lines accordingly:
wsl --shutdown
cd ~\Documents
mkdir WSL\images
mkdir WSL\instances\UbuntuRecovery
wsl --export Ubuntu WSL\images\ubuntu.tar
wsl --import UbuntuRecovery WSL\instances\UbuntuRecovery WSL\images\ubuntu.tar --version 1
wsl -d UbuntuRecovery
```

See if the file is gone or deletable in that new instance.

If so, and if everything else looks okay in the new instance, then:

- Set the default username in that instance via a `/etc/wsl.conf` file per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).
- Exit the instance
- Again, from PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --terminate UbuntuRecovery
  wsl --set-default UbuntuRecovery
  ```

The new instance will be the default whenever `wsl` is run.

Finally, remove the original corrupted instance with:

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu
```

**Important**:  This is a **destructive** operation.  Make sure that everything is working as intended.  On the bright side, we've made a backup already ...

You can also uninstall the Ubuntu "App" that was installed from the Store at that point.

You'll launch via `wsl` (if you haven't been already) or Windows Terminal since the `ubuntu.exe` (or `ubuntu2004.exe`) command will be gone.